# I need a control like TX TextControl, can Office API provide that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, office-js, txtextcontrol

At the moment I need a text control that i can integrate in a ASP.NET MVC. TX TextControl can cover most of the requirements I need, but it is not very customizable. I am looking in to Office API, Office js and Office 365. And i was wondering if you have any suggestion how that can be done, if it can be done at all.

The closest I have found is [TX TextControl](http://www.textcontrol.com/).

I need a text control where i can create templates, add header and footer to the templates, input data from database, and in general that has MS Word specific capabilities.

If you have any other suggestions, besides TX TextControl or Office API. 
I am open to suggestions and ideas.

Comment: I have been using DevExpress components for years. They have a control were you can create headers, footers (not sure on the templates) https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxRichEditDemos/Overview

Comment: @RegencySoftware, I haven't considered DevExpress and its components. Will look in to them. Thank you, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office's JavaScript API provides endpoints for extending Office applications (Word, Excel, Outlook, etc.). It does not support embedding Office apps into 3rd party solutions. In other words, you can augments the editing experience in Word but you cannot leverage Word as an editing control within your own app.